# i am trying to getting error in nullsefty error please give me answer

Tags: android

i am using retrofit library and my app crashing  and in logcat error in **nullpointerexception**

```
var animalcall:Call<List<animaldashmodel>>
=apiinterface.animal_viewdata()
        animalcall.enqueue(object :Callback<List<animaldashmodel>>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<animaldashmodel>>,
                response: Response<List<animaldashmodel>>
            ) {
                list=response.body() as MutableList<animaldashmodel>

                var adapter=Animal_Dashboard_Adapter(applicationContext,list)
                binding.recycle.adapter=adapter
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<animaldashmodel>>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

this is my logcat and i want to want right answer

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                             Process: com.example.myanimal, PID: 28943
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.MutableList<com.example.myanimal.AppModel.animaldashmodel>
at com.example.myanimal.Activity.Animal_Dashboardview_activity$onCreate$1.onResponse(Animal_Dashboardview_activity.kt:40)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely stems from here. Since there is not much detail, I recommend using it this way.

```
list=response.body() as MutableList<animaldashmodel>
```

to

```
    try {    
       list=response.body() as? MutableList<animaldashmodel>
} catch (e : Exception){
       Log.d("TAG","Exception")
        }
```